# Terraform: If-else not working with alb_lb_listener resource

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create resource `aws_lb_listener` with terraform interpolation for if-else condition. But It says me there is no change in the infrastructure. However, It has not created https listener yet on the infrastructure. Is anything missing in below code ?

alb.tf

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "https" {
  count = "${var.https_listener_enable == true ? 1 : 0}"
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.main.arn}"
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = "arn:aws:iam::187416307283:server-certificate/test_cert_rab3wuqwgja25ct3n4jdj2tzu4"

  default_action {
    type = "fixed-response"

  fixed_response {
      content_type = "text/plain"
      message_body = "Nothing is here. Go Away."
      status_code  = "200"
    }
}
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "https_listener_enable" {}
```

main.tf

```
module "public_alb" {
  source             = "../modules/alb"
  load_balancer_name = "example-production"
  https_listener_enable = true
  security_groups            = ["${module.security_group.sg_http}"]
  load_balancer_is_internal  = false
  idle_timeout               = 60
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  enable_http2               = true
  tags                       = "${map("Environment", "production",
                "Name", "example-production",)}"
  subnets = "${module.vpc.public_subnets}"

  vpc_id = "${module.vpc.vpc_id}"
}
```

Comment: Your ternary is requiring that `https_listener_enable` be set to `true`, so you are probably not doing that anywhere. You are not doing it in any of the displayed code at least.

Comment: In main.tf I am passing that variable as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing count value to this `"${var.https_listener_enable ? 1 : 0}"` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Replace count = "${var.https_listener_enable == true ? 1 : 0}" with count = "${var.https_listener_enable == "true" ? 1 : 0}" . This should work if you have already defined variable "https_listener_enable" value in .tfvars file or passing  from commandline .

Comment: I haven't tested this solution yet. But it seems this should work.